# add an active state in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

In jQuery I often add a class "active" to let me know if a div/img or whatever is in an active state. I have a group of mc's and would like to toggle on/off an active state. Is this possible is as3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use a custom property for the MovieClip, example :

```
myMc.isactive = false;
     ^^^^^^^^
[you can use any word]
```

Comment: Following AS3 coding standards, it would be `active`.